# WP7 Custom MultiColumnStackPanel Items child already has parent

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mobile

I'm using an example from [this](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/multi-column-stackpanel-0) site to create a MultiColumnStackPanel.

There is however one problem. Once the page is loaded, the stackpanel looks fine and exactly like the example. But when I navigate to a next page and then go back to the previous one I get an exception:

```
InvalidOperationException
```

With the following message:

```
Element is already the child of another element.
```

.

So I think that the items that were contained in the original custom stackpanel are being added to a new custom stackpanel. But then why is the **MultiColumnStackPanel** being 'refreshed' and do the **MultiColumnStackPanel.Items** persist?

Does anyone else have a explanation/solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance

.

**MultiColumnStackPanel class:**

```
public class MultiColumnStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    public int NumberOfColumns { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items",
            typeof(Collection<UIElement>),
            typeof(MultiColumnStackPanel),
            new PropertyMetadata(new Collection<UIElement>()));

    public Collection<UIElement> Items
    {
        get { return (Collection<UIElement>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    }

    public MultiColumnStackPanel()
    {
        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            LoadItems();
        };
    }

    void LoadItems()
    {
        Children.Clear();

        if (Items != null)
        {
            StackPanel sp = CreateNewStackPanel();
            foreach (UIElement item in Items)
            {
                sp.Children.Add(item);
                if (sp.Children.Count == NumberOfColumns)
                {
                    Children.Add(sp);
                    sp = CreateNewStackPanel();
                }
            }

            if (sp.Children.Count > 0)
                Children.Add(sp);
        }
    }

    private StackPanel CreateNewStackPanel()
    {
        Orientation oppositeOrientation;

        if(this.Orientation.Equals(Orientation.Vertical))
            oppositeOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        else
            oppositeOrientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        return new StackPanel() { Orientation = oppositeOrientation };
    }
}
```

**xaml example:**

```
<model:MultiColumnStackPanel x:Name="customStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" NumberOfColumns="2">
    <model:MultiColumnStackPanel.Items>
        <Rectangle Height="80" Width="80" Margin="10" Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Height="80" Width="80" Margin="10" Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Height="80" Width="80" Margin="10" Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Height="80" Width="80" Margin="10" Fill="Green" />
    </model:MultiColumnStackPanel.Items>
</model:MultiColumnStackPanel>
```

Comment: Carefully debug the application step by step. When Navigated back,Loaded event is again raised, I guess thats causing the issue for YOu.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and thought I'd share my findings.

In the constructor of the MultiColumnStackPanel the function `LoadItems()` is bound to the `Loaded` event of the StackPanel.

When navigating to the next page and then navigating back, the MultiColumnStackPanel is not being created again as I thought earlier. The `Loaded` event of the MultiColumnStackPanel is simply fired again.

```
public MultiColumnStackPanel()
{
    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        LoadItems();
    };
}
```

Then I saw that each time the `LoadItems()` function was called it cleared the children of the object. Removing this did the trick, if the children are already present there's no need to add them from the `Items` list again.

```
void LoadItems()
{
    // Children.Clear();

    if (Items != null && (Children == null || Children.Count == 0))
    {
        StackPanel sp = CreateNewStackPanel();
        foreach (UIElement item in Items)
        {
            sp.Children.Add(item);
            if (sp.Children.Count == NumberOfColumns)
            {
                Children.Add(sp);
                sp = CreateNewStackPanel();
            }
        }
        if (sp.Children.Count > 0)
            Children.Add(sp);
    }
}
```

Sometimes all you need a little self-reflection =)

**EDIT**

One more note, `ItemsProperty` should not be static

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = // <-- remove static
    DependencyProperty.Register("Items",
    typeof(Collection<UIElement>),
    typeof(MultiColumnStackPanel),
    new PropertyMetadata(new Collection<UIElement>()));
```

Comment: I am just wondering, You solved the problem without the help of my above comment?

Comment: Partly, thanks to your comment I further explored the Loaded event ;)